# Hamburger Menu open on page load

Tags: javascript, html

I have an issue where my Hamburger menu is open on page load.  It functions as desired other than that.  If i click on it it closes and then opens as well onclick.

```
<div class="topnav">
  <a href="#home" class="active">Dashboard</a>
  <!-- Navigation links (hidden by default) -->
  <div id="nav">
                <a href="/index.php"><i class="fas fa-user-circle"></i>Profile</a>
                <a href="../user/invoices.php"><i class="fas fa-user-circle"></i>Invoices</a>
                <a href="/post"><i class="fas fa-user-circle"></i>Post Message</a>
                <a href="/register"><i class="fas fa-user-circle"></i>New User</a>
                <a href="/logout.php"><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i>Logout</a>
  </div>
  <!-- "Hamburger menu" / "Bar icon" to toggle the navigation links -->
  <a href="javascript:void();" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </a>
</div>

<script>
/* Toggle between showing and hiding the navigation menu links when the user clicks on the hamburger menu / bar icon */
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("nav");
  if (x.style.display === "block") {
    x.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "block";
  }
}
</script>
```

CSS

```
* {

    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "segoe ui", roboto, oxygen, ubuntu, cantarell, "fira sans", "droid sans", "helvetica neue", Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
body {
    background-color: #435165;

}
.login {
    width: 400px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 9px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    margin: 100px auto;
}
.login h1 {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #737373;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 24px;
    padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dee0e4;
}
.login form {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
.login form label {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #737373;
    color: #ffffff;
}
.login form input[type="password"], .login form input[type="text"] {
    width: 310px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #dee0e4;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding: 0 15px;
}
.login form input[type="submit"] {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    background-color: #737373;
    border: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #ffffff;
    transition: background-color 0.2s;
}
.login form input[type="submit"]:hover {
    background-color: #ef1d1d;
    transition: background-color 0.2s;
}





.content {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.content h2 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 25px 0;
    font-size: 22px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e0e0e3;
    color: #4a536e;
}
.content > p, .content > div {
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    margin: 25px 0;
    padding: 25px;
    background-color: #fff;
}
.content > p table td, .content > div table td {
    padding: 5px;
}
.content > p table td:first-child, .content > div table td:first-child {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #4a536e;
    padding-right: 15px;
}
.content > div p {
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}


/* For Posting announcements */

.form-contact {
  max-width: 330px;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.form-contact .form-contact-heading,
.form-contact .checkbox {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.form-contact .checkbox {
  font-weight: normal;
}
.form-contact .form-control {
  position: relative;
  height: auto;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.form-contact .form-control:focus {
  z-index: 2;
}
.form-contact input[type="email"] {
  margin-bottom: -1px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}
.container { background-color: #435165;}

@media print {
  body {
    display: none;
  }
}




.col-md-12{
    background-color: white;

}


















/* Style the navigation menu */
.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: relative;
}

/* Hide the links inside the navigation menu (except for logo/home) */
.topnav #myLinks {
  display: none;
}

/* Style navigation menu links */
.topnav a {
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  display: block;
}

/* Style the hamburger menu */
.topnav a.icon {
  background: #ef1d1d;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

/* Add a grey background color on mouse-over */
.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

/* Style the active link (or home/logo) */
.active {
  background-color: #737373;
  color: white;
}
```

What could be causing this issue within the above script?  I have looked all over it to see.  The javascript appears correct but im clearly missing something.

Comment: Your function `myFunction` does not call unless there is a click on your icon, thus it never runs on page load... Call in on doc ready or use the solution from @francois

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add this to your css:

```
#nav{
  display:none;
}
```

It will hide your `#nav` `div` by default, i.e. on page load. Alternatively, you could use Javascript to hide `#nav` on page load by adding:

```
// self executing function
(function() {
      var x = document.getElementById("nav");
      x.style.display = "none";
})();
```

This will make your `myFunction();` method ready to use on page load.

Since it is often appropriate with a menu like that, and because it is only 4 additional lines, you may want to consider using this third method, which will keep the toggle state of your menu if/when the page is reloaded:

```
// self executing function
(function() {
    if(window.localStorage.getItem('nav') === null){
      window.localStorage.setItem('nav', 'none');
    }
    var x = document.getElementById("nav");
    x.style.display = window.localStorage.getItem('nav');
})();

function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("nav");
    if (x.style.display === "block") {
      x.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      x.style.display = "block";
    }
    window.localStorage.setItem('nav', x.style.display);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I dont know how i missed that .. worked like a charm.

Comment: @DavidMorin no problem!

Comment: This is the answer, but it would be more complete if you also added the JS call to make his `myFunction` method work on window load. Maybe, somebody wants a full JS solution, seems silly here but it is possible

Comment: no problem, you are right it could be usefull, i'll edit

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS like this:

```
#nav{
  display:none;
}
```

But if you want to do something when the body loads you can add a function like this:

```
<body onload="onload()">
```

and the function:

```
function onload() {
  var x = document.getElementById("nav");
  x.style.display = "none";
}
```

Check it out here:
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/estebancervantes/zms4bpx6/1/)